# Which cipher is more secure TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA or TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, tls

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA supports forward secrecy but it doesn't use GCM mode and use SHA1 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 uses GCM mode and SHA2 but it doesn't support forward secrecy. Which one is more secure?

Comment: Where do you want to use it? What is the attack model?

Comment: one the iis web server

Comment: Use TLS 1.3 and prevent TLS 1.2 cipher suites. This is the way.

Comment: but my iis server is windows server 2012 it doesn't support tls1.3

Comment: Update your server? Windows Server 2012 mainstream support ended in 2018, the other unpatched security flaws mean this choice is irrelevant.

Comment: You should use only FS enabled ciphersuites so `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` is clearly a better option (and is TLS 1.0 compatible). Check out [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1) list and prefer FS enabled ciphersuites at the top only. Also, note that HMAC-SHA1 is different than SHA1 so no need to worry it's "broken" already.